# About integration on manifold and partition of unity (and finiteness of open covers)

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds

Please see the definition below of integration over a boundary of a Lipschitz domain. My question is, the summation in (C.36) for example is over $n$. But when is this a finite sum? If $\partial\Omega$ is bounded then can we say that the sum is a finite sum? Why is that?? Is it not sufficient to consider a finite number of points $x_0 \in \partial\Omega$ such that $\{A_{x_0}\}$ covers $\partial\Omega$?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The sum in (C.36) may be finite or infinite. As noted in the previous line, the family of functions $\psi_n$ is locally finite, which suggests that the author allows for the possibility of the family being infinite. But if $\Omega$ is a bounded domain, then $\partial \Omega$ is compact, so we can choose a finite subcover $(A_{x_n})$ and have finitely many functions $\psi_n$.

It seems the author did not feel like discussing the convergence of the integral $\int_{\partial \Omega} u\,d\mathcal{H}^{N-1}$. This is a pity because if $u$ is allowed to change sign (as it is, according to "$u:\partial \Omega\to\mathbb R$" in the penultimate sentence), the validity of (C.36) is not assured. It is possible that the integral on the left may diverge while the series on the right converges.

Also, the author applies (C.35) to $u\psi_n$, but (C.35) is stated for nonnegative functions only.

I think the way to fix all the above is to require "$u:\partial \Omega\to [0,\infty]$" in the penultimate sentence. Then (C.36) is true unconditionally, if one allows for $\infty=\infty$, as is customary. The integral of general $u$ can be defined later by $$\int_{\partial \Omega}u = \int_{\partial \Omega}u^+ -\int_{\partial \Omega}u^- $$
where we require that at least one integral on the right is finite.